# Socket Select() is working but Poll() is not working correctly

Tags: linux, sockets, unix-socket

I am calling my function eventOnSocket() again and again to check if there is any event on the sockets.

My code is working fine If I use select but If I use poll then my code is not working correctly. In case of poll, I am getting the timeout error.

Here it is working code with select.

```
int eventOnSocket() 
{
    int retVal = -1;
    int socketMax = -1;
    struct timeval tv;
    tv.tv_sec = 15; //sec
    tv.tv_usec = 0; //microsec
    FD_ZERO(&m_rfds);

    for(int i = 0; i < m_sockList.size(); i++) 
    {
        int socketId = task->m_sockList.at(i);
        if(socketMax < socketId)
            socketMax = socketId;
        FD_SET(socketId, m_rfds);
    }
    if(socketMax > 0) {
        retVal = select(socketMax+1, &m_rfds, NULL, NULL, &tv);
        return retVal;
    }
    else
        return -1;
}
```

But when I use Poll in the same way then I get timeout error. In poll I am assigning the socket fds only once in a vector when I call the function first time and then I call the function again and again to check any event on the sockets.

Here is the code with poll.

```
int eventOnSocket()
{
    /* Assign socket fds only once in a vector when function is called first time only*/
    if(true == assignSocktOnlyOnce)
    {       
        assignSocktOnlyOnce = false;

        for(int i=0; i < m_sockList.size(); i++) 
        {
            INT32_N socketId = m_sockList.at(i);
            struct pollfd pfd;
            pfd.fd = socketId;
            pfd.events = POLLIN;

            ufds.push_back(pfd);
        }
    }
    retVal = poll(&ufds[0],(nfds_t)ufds.size(), 15000);
    if (retVal == -1) {
            LOG_ERR("===  error in  Polling === "); 
    }
    else if (retVal == 0) {
            LOG_ERR("Timeout occurred!  No data after 15 seconds.");
    }
    else {
            for(int i = 0; i < ufds.size(); i++) {
                if (ufds[i].revents & POLLIN )
                        LOG_ERR("Read for socket fd:%d",ufds[i].fd);
            }
    }
    return retVal;
}

ufds is vector defined in .h file
std::vector<struct pollfd> ufds ;
```

Answer (score 0):

> In poll I am assigning the socket fds only once in a vector when I call the function first time and then I call the function again and again to check any event on the sockets.

That could explain why these two code paths behave differently. Make your poll code rebuild `ufds` every time for the sake of checking.